# Scale container to monitor size without losing scrollbar?

Tags: css, html, scrollbar, containers, scale

On my website I have a div that contains all the main text and content of the website but it's on a fixed height which means that on larger monitors the container doesn't scale vertically as I would like it to do.

I tried setting the css properties for the div to be 'auto' in height however this makes it so that the scrollbar within the container is removed entirely and the page just stretches out endlessly rather than it being contained within the container but still scale to monitor size.

I want to make the container adjust to screen size vertically depending on the browser size without losing the scrollbar within the content container itself. How can I best go about achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the height to a percentage and the overflow to auto. Set overflow to "scroll" if you want the scroll bars to be there all the time.

```
#mydiv {
height: 80%;
overflow: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z9j3M/